# How to detect Databricks environment programmatically

Tags: java, apache-spark, databricks

I'm writing a spark job that needs to be runnable locally as well as on Databricks.

The code has to be slightly different in each environment (file paths) so I'm trying to find a way to detect if the job is running in Databricks. The best way I have found so far was to look for a "dbfs" directory in the root dir and if it's there then assume it's running on Databricks. This doesn't feel like the right solution. Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Set an environment variable when running on Databricks? and not/another when running locally? similar to a dev/production seperation.

Comment: Can you pass parameter such profile ? On Databricks is cluster mode ?

Comment: @steven35 Would you build it as jar and run it via `spark-submit` job?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can simply check for the existence of an environment variable e.g.:

```
def isRunningInDatabricks(): Boolean = 
  sys.env.contains("DATABRICKS_RUNTIME_VERSION")
```

Comment: In Python, the condition would be ```"DATABRICKS_RUNTIME_VERSION" in os.environ```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

Python:

```
def isLocal():
    setting = spark.conf.get("spark.master")
    return ("local" in setting)
```

Scala:

```
def isLocal(): Boolean = {
    val setting = spark.conf.get("spark.master")
    return ("local" contains setting)
}
```

Comment: I got 'local[*]' on azure dbs china.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for spark configuration environment variable such as   ***"spark.home"*** and value as */databricks/spark*

python:
sc._conf.get("spark.home")

result:
'/databricks/spark'

Comment: That's a good approach but the reason why I need to know if it's running on Databricks in the first place is so that I can create the config and context accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. Databricks notebooks are not files.

```py
# If it is a file...
try:
    __file__
    print("It is a file")
except NameError:
    print("It is a Databricks notebook")
```